# MongoDB - How to map a model class to a single field in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Suppose I have this model class

```
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    internal class SomeData
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public ObjectId ABCId { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
```

and I want to store this data in a format something like

```
collection user
{
    _id: ObjectId(),

    **lots of other data**

    SomeData: {
        ABCId: ObjectId(),
        Number: 5
    }
}
```

Collection user consists of multiple model classes.
for example the above model deals with 2 fields only, while another model will deal with few other fields in the same collection/document.

My questions are :-

1) How to map an entire model class to one field in mongodb C#?

2) How to save/load efficiently by selecting only "SomeData" field from database?

3) Is this ok to break down a document into multiple model classes and handle save/load separately whenever required?

Thank you

Comment: You can have a parent model which has a property of type submodel. 
You can use Builders<T>.Update, and Builders<T>.Projection, these will update/select the specified field only.
Yes it is ok and I think it is always better to do so

Comment: @Munzer thats what I went with myself, and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] worked for me.